# From VMware Fusion to Bootcamp on Mac

Tags: macos, windows-7, bootcamp, vmware-fusion

I am doing quite a lot of .NET development on my Mac. I've got VMware Fusion 3 installed with Windows 7 Professional. From there I am running Visual Studio 2010. As I am doing more and more development, at times I would like to boot directly into Windows using Bootcamp. So here comes the question:

How can I port my Windows installation from VMware Fusion to Bootcamp?

I have been try to search for some tools to do this trick but I haven't had any luck in finding such a tool yet. Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks a lot. I look forward to hearing from you! :-)

Cheers,
Sebastian

Comment: You might get better answers on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com) since this is more of a OS X question than programming.

Comment: @Kraaij, I would like to know that is it working smooth when you develop .NET application on Mac. I'm planning to do it as well but not yet found comment about this. Could you give some comments?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I think the best method is don't even bother. I've tried doing that transfer numerous times and it just never works out. I've ended up with non-bootable systems, partially bootable, and just a mishmash in between. If you do find a solution do tell, but I spent a few days on that same issue before finally realizing that just reformatting and installing fresh into Boot Camp is the way to go.